# Image and container in docker after a new build

Tags: docker

I've just started with Docker and I have a question given the following scenario:

1. I build an image
2. I run such an image in a container
3. I notice that I've missed something in the Dockerfile and I build a new version of the image

My question is: does the container know about the updated image? If not, what is the right workflow? So far I do this: stop the container -> remove it -> create a new one with the same name from the latest image .... but I don't think that it is the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does the container know about the updated image?

No, your container is still using everything in the image based on which it started.

> what is the right workflow?

1. Stop your previous container
2. Run a new container using your newer image

Note: you could either `docker rm` your previous container or not to do so, but if you want to run your new container with the same container name, you have to remove the previous one.

Comment: A container is just a isolation environment for a running process, and when you build your new image, docker will use overlay FS and add new layers for new image on copy-on-write way. So for a running container, its image is kinds of "static" stuff. If you want to pass image info to that process, you can run your container with `-e` to define new environment variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shuzhz. Can you point me to a tutorial on how to use such environment variables?

Comment: @user3727540, glad to help:-) you can refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables for more details. A simple example is `docker run --rm -e "FOO=BAR" alpine:3.3 env`, it'll start a container, then run command `env` inside it to list all environment variables of the container and exit. You will see `FOO=BAR` in the output.

Answer (score -1):

It's enough to stop the running container and start it again. It should pick up the latest built version of the image.